# Understanding density functions

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is it possible to prove that a probability distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue without using its density function ?

I am wondering about this because I thought that density functions are defined only once the distribution is known to be absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure

I am getting confused

Comment: A proof will likely involve the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Proving that a probability distribution $P$ on measurable space $(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure *precedes* the definition of a density.

It is enough for that to prove that $\lambda(B)=0\implies P(B)=0$ for Borel sets $B$ and then to *invoke* the Radon-Nikodym theorem (as commented by Math1000). This together proves that a density *exists*.

Comment: How can you show that for Borel sets $B$, $\lambda (B) = 0 \implies P(B) = 0$ for a normal distribution, without using the density function ?

Comment: A general answer cannot be given on that. It depends on $P$. In the case that $P$ has a density you are ready at once.